# Dynamic Variables / eval / string evaluation in Azure Devops Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How do I do an 'eval' in an Azure DevOps pipeline? I tried eval in a bash step and it said eval didn't exist.

For example:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
    var: 'middle'
    start_middle_end: '123'

name: 'test'

steps:
- bash: |
    echo $(start_$(var)_end)
    echo $(start_$[var]_end)
    echo $[start_$(var)_end]
    ${{format('{0} {1}', 'echo', '$(start_$(var)_end)')}}
```

What I'd like it to do is echo 123. You can see various attempts above. What is actually says is:

```
2020-03-15T19:00:20.9585338Z /d/a/_temp/704b13e7-2bb0-4099-98a9-292925b35f19.sh: line 1: start_middle_end: command not found
2020-03-15T19:00:20.9721864Z /d/a/_temp/704b13e7-2bb0-4099-98a9-292925b35f19.sh: line 2: start_0_end: command not found
2020-03-15T19:00:20.9741785Z 0
2020-03-15T19:00:20.9864319Z /d/a/_temp/704b13e7-2bb0-4099-98a9-292925b35f19.sh: line 4: start_middle_end: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with PowerShell in this way:

```
variables:
    var: 'middle'
    start_middle_end: '123'


steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $middleVar= "$(var)"
      $startEndVar= "start_$($middleVar)_end"
      $startEndVarValue = (Get-item env:$startEndVar).Value
      Write-Host $startEndVarValue
      # The output will be: 123
```

Comment: In PowerShell, one could also use Invoke-Expression which is the PowerShell equivalent of eval. I'd hoped to use Bash as I am trying to maintain cross-platform support as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/cross-platform-scripting?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml. Any Bash way to do it?

Comment: I have just tried an eval again and this time the eval worked in bash. Previously it said that eval didn't exist. I am investigating and will report back.

Comment: I can't find why eval didn't originally work. Therefore, marking the PowerShell answer as an answer.

Comment: @Mark I don’t know why :(

Comment: According to the documentation you should be able to use the [PowerShell Core syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#pwsh) to maintain your cross-platform support